# android bottomSheet can not update child size programmatically

Tags: android, bottom-sheet

it's hard to me to explain this problem, but you can see the below layout code,
First i have the layout look like this:
[image]

[image]

yeah, this is the call screen using webrtc, when i have the video, put it into main_render, the change the size when i have delegate for video size:

```
main_render.setScalingType(RendererCommon.ScalingType.SCALE_ASPECT_FIT)
        main_render.init(rootEglBase.eglBaseContext, object : RendererCommon.RendererEvents{
            override fun onFirstFrameRendered() {
                Log.e(TAG, "onFirstFrameRendered")
            }

            override fun onFrameResolutionChanged(i: Int, i1: Int, i2: Int) {
                Log.e(TAG, "onFrameResolutionChanged: $i - $i1")
                runOnUiThread {
                    val newParams = main_render.layoutParams as FrameLayout.LayoutParams
                    newParams.width = dm.widthPixels
                    newParams.height = i1 * dm.widthPixels / i
                    main_render.layoutParams = newParams
                    main_render.requestLayout()
                    main_layout.updateViewLayout(main_render, newParams)
                    main_layout.requestLayout()
                }
            }
        })
```

But the problem is the size does not changed, i have to press to hide sheet, press again to show sheet then now the size is change ( i have onclick to hide and show collapse sheet)

Can someone help me know this problem, when remove sheet and using main_layout it's work normally, but when using sheet the size can not changed immediately

Answer (score 0):

Try to set state of BottomSheet after update viewlayout if it helps:

```
  val behavior = bottomSheetDialog.behavior
        behavior.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED
```